# how to manipulate HashMap while accessing?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

can any body help me by giving the answer with example that how to remove entries from HashMap while accessing entries.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) besides asking us?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "while accessing entries"? Are we talking multiple threads (use ConcurrentHashMap) or while iterating over entries (use Iterator.remove)?

Answer (score 1):

Use [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

> A hash table supporting full concurrency of retrievals and adjustable expected concurrency for updates.

Here is a nice [example](http://www.concretestudy.com/corejava/example_concurrenthashmap.php)

Answer (score 0):

Through the entries iterator :

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
myMap.put("test", "test1");
myMap.put("test2", "test2");
Iterator<Entry<String, String>> it = myMap.entrySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    if("test".equals(it.next().getKey())) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to iterate on a copy of the keys:

```
final Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("test", 0);
map.put("removeMe", 1);
map.put("dontRemoveMe", 2);
for (final String key : map.keySet().toArray(new String[map.keySet().size()]))
    if (key.startsWith("remove"))
        map.remove(key);
```

But if your `Map` is larger than a few entries, you may encounter bad performances, and you may want to use the `iterator` remove:

```
final Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> iter = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext())
    if (iter.next().getKey().startsWith("remove"))
        iter.remove();
```